# Why is my React component's refs equal to undefined within a test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, karma-runner

How can I access `refs` from within a component during testing? I've tried using `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` (a la http://myshareoftech.com/2013/12/unit-testing-react-dot-js-with-jasmine-and-karma.html) and `TestUtils.createRenderer().render()`, but in both cases, my component's `refs` seems to be undefined (running Jasmine/Karma in both PhantomJS and Chrome). Is there something I'm missing?

My assumption was that this might be due to changes in 0.14 with splitting ReactDOM out, but I have no way to verify that.

Here's my code:

```js
import React from 'react'; // v0.14
import TestUtils from 'react/lib/ReactTestUtils';
import SeatList from '../../client/seat-list';

describe('SeatList', () => {
  // using ReactShallowRenderer
  var renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
  function getRenderedResult(props = {}) {
    renderer.render(<SeatList playerColor={props.playerColor || null}
                white={props.white || undefined}
                black={props.black || undefined}
                sitOrStandAs={props.sitOrStandAs || null} />);
    return renderer.getRenderOutput();
  }
  it('allows a user to sit in an open seat', () => {
    let sitOrStandAs = jasmine.createSpy('sitOrStandAs');

    let result = getRenderedResult({sitOrStandAs: sitOrStandAs});
    console.log(result.refs); // result.refs is undefined :(

    // using TestUtils.renderIntoDocument
    let seatList = <SeatList playerColor={null} white={undefined} black={undefined} sitOrStandAs={sitOrStandAs} />;
    TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(seatList);

    let btn = seatList.refs.white; // throws Exception: seatList.refs is undefined :(
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(btn);
    expect(sitOrStandAs).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was under the false impression that `renderIntoDocument` didn't return anything useful. The right solution is to assign seatList to the return value of `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument`:

```
let seatList = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(seatList);
```

Following this, tests pass, and I feel happier now.